# I have a text file with two parts. I want to split two parts into two lists. (python help)

Tags: python-3.x, list, file, split

data.txt

diuwhwhpjd
huntinghik
bebwubkwue
examplehuh
uwhiqhuhhd
hsiuhhdukj

example
hunting

I want to make two list from this data in one file. The first list will contain all the data before blank line and second list will contain the words after the blank line. Also [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R01cv.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try out the below code:

```
list1 = []
list2 = []
temp_list = []
with open('data.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        if not line.strip():
            list1 = temp_list
            temp_list = []
        else:
            temp_list.append(line.strip())
    list2 = temp_list
```

Hope this solves your problem!